# Why does scala method not accept generic?

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following 2 methods:

```
def callAlpha = call[T](Constants.Alpha)(_: String)(_: T => T)

def call[T](symbol: String)(caller: String)(op: T => T)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): String = { // some code }
```

Eclipse complains about the use of generics in the first method, but not in the second. Why is this?

Comment: Is there a declaration `type ->[A, B] = ...` or `trait ->[A, B] { ... }` somewhere in scope, or was this supposed to be `T => T`?

Comment: argh it was supposed to be T => T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second method you include a *type parameter* definition (`[T]` which immediately follows the *method name*). This declares a type parameter named `T` (you can name it however you want) which can then be used in the method's input arguments, output type, and implementation.

The first method is missing this definition - it attempts to use a type named `T` without declaring such a type: the method name (`callAlpha`) is not followed by a similar type parameter definition and therefore the *method body* (`call[T](Constants.Alpha)(_: String)(_: T -> T)`) cannot use it.

The fix can be simple - define `T` for the first method too:

```
def callAlpha[T] = call[T](Constants.Alpha)(_: String)(_: T => T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in

```
def callAlpha = call[T](Constants.Alpha)(_: String)(_: T => T)
```

there is an unbound type variable `T` on the right hand side.

You probably meant:

```
def callAlpha[T] = call(Constants.Alpha)(_: String)(_: T => T)
```